# Parse expression

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have some collection `List<ObjectId>` called 'ids'. I want to allow users to create flexible filters for 'ids'.

I would like to create a textbox, into which user must to write a filter string. For example:

```
item => item.ClassName == "Rectangle"
```

This expression I need apply for each item on 'ids'. How can I try parse it for validation? How can I run it in my code for each 'ids' item?

Comment: This is the way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: @Cuong Le it is class, not structure.

Comment: @BlackBear thank you for link, but I don't see how can I parse expression from string.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx, is it safe to expose such functionality to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I think, it is a that I necessary! Thank you!

Comment: @Bush: you can call `AsQueryable()` first

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a class that extends List, then you can create get method like:

```
public class ObjectIdCollection : List<ObjectId>
{
    public ObjectIdCollection() { }
    public ObjectId this[string classname]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach(ObjectId id in this) if(id.ClassName == classname) return id;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This will either return the first Id with the classname specified, or null if none is found

Comment: No, expression for filter can be ANY. User must set it through textbox. And I must use it expression.

Answer (score 0):

They are many [lambda expression parsers](http://code.google.com/p/lambda-parser/downloads/detail?name=Zhucai.LambdaParser.dll&can=2&q=) available.

Use the below logic to parse and execute the based on textbox (Say `txtFilter`) filter string.

```
var ids = new List<ObjectId> 
             { 
                new ObjectId { ClassName = "Rectangle1", ID = 1 }, 
                new ObjectId { ClassName = "Rectangle2", ID = 2 } 
             };

string code = txtFilter.Text; (Ex: "item => item.ClassName == \"Rectangle1\"" ;)

Func<ObjectId, bool> func = ExpressionParser.Compile<Func<ObjectId, bool>>(code);      

ids.ForEach(obejctId => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(func.Invoke(obejctId));
        });
```

Output is

```
  True
  False
```